# Flink: ValueState vs ReducingState/AggregatingState

Tags: apache-flink

## Background

- `ValueState` documentation states: `partitioned single-value state`.
- `ReducingState` documentation states: `combined using a reduce function`.
- `AggregatingState` documentation states: `eagerly pre-aggregated`.
- `ValueState` extends `State` while both `ReducingState` and `AggregatingState` extends `MergingState`.

### Questions

1. When do states merge?
2. How should I choose the right state primitive for a certain problem?
3. What mechanism invokes the reduce and aggregate function? Does it skip non-`MergingState`?

Answer (score 2):

Fabian Hueske answered a question from me about merging in AggregateFunctions a while ago (May 6, 2018). He said:

> The only situation when merge() is called in a DataStream job (that I am aware of) is when session windows get merged.
>   For example when you define a session window with 30 minute gap and you receive the following records
>   R1, 12:00:00
>   R2, 12:05:00
>   R3, 12:40:00
>   R4, 12:20:00
>
> In this case, Flink R1 will create a new window W1, R2 will be assigned to W1, R3 > creates a new window W2, and R4 connects and merges W1 and W2.

I think a partial answer to your other questions is that `ValueState` is generic (keyed) state. So you wind up using this when you're implementing generic functions, not aggregators or reducers (with combiners).

Comment: In the `merge()` case mentioned above, how will a `ValueState` be merged?

Comment: `ValueState` doesn't extend `MergingState`, so it's not used for merging. A `ValueState` is for state that you're managing in a custom function.

Comment: What do you refer by "custom function" or "generic functions"? I couldn't find anywhere in the docs a situation in which `ValueState` can be used while `AggregatingState` should be avoided.

Comment: If I have say `MyFunction extends RichMapFunction`, and I need to maintain state, then I'd use a `ValueState` (or `ListState` or `MapState`). So in this case `MyFunction` is a custom function, versus the use of `AggregatingState` with an accumulator function.